# (optimization) Do i change "SpriteRenderer.Sprite" to the same texture every frame, or condition before?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know it's a simple question but i really don't know the answer, what is the the most optimize way to do ?

first (condition) :

```
        if (sprRenderer.Sprite != Sprites[Frame])
        {
            SprRenderer.sprite = Sprites[Frame];
            Debug.Log("draw");
        }
```

second (without condition) :

```
            SprRenderer.sprite = Sprites[Frame];
            Debug.Log("draw");
```

if you want more details that it's the update code (on start 'timer' = 1, 'AnimParameter' it's an event that loop animation, 'NameAnimation' it's this animation) :

```
    void Update() {

    Timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (Timer >= 1f / FramePerSec)
    {
        if (Frame < Sprites.Length - 1)
        {
            Frame++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (AnimParameter.CurrentAnimation != NameAnimation)
            {
                enabled = false;
            }

            Frame = 0;
        }

        SprRenderer.sprite = Sprites[Frame];
        Debug.Log("draw");


        Timer = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to change the sprite?  If your doing animations the best way would be to use the animation system built into unity, or to create a delegate/event and change the sprite only on an event.

Comment: i have create an event but i also add loop to this event, the sprite is 
constantly changing